# ArrayFire af::where time consumption

Tags: arrayfire

I have an af::array for which i want to find the non zero location (2048*2048).

```
af::timer start1 = af::timer::start();
af::array index = af::where(mat); // for the first time
cout << "elapsed time (ms): " << af::timer::stop(start1)*1000 <<" ms"<<endl;
start1 = af::timer::start();
index = af::where(mat); //for the second time
cout << "elapsed time (ms): " << af::timer::stop(start1)*1000 <<" ms"<<endl;
```

First iteration:

```
elapsed time (ms) : 1.8792 ms
elapsed time (ms) : 0.7094 ms
```

Second iteration:

```
elapsed time (ms) : 16.8074 ms
elapsed time (ms) : 0.4738 ms
```

Third iteration

```
elpased time (ms) : 17.3236 ms
elpased time (ms) : 0.4543 ms
```

Why are the times is so inconsistent?

Comment: What you posted clearly isn't the exact output of that code you showed, but I have edited it for readability

Comment: Hey, I have answered your queries in our google-forums conversation already https://groups.google.com/g/arrayfire-users/c/47RYzDQpzc4/m/NvsPYbUYAwAJ 

please have a look.

Comment: Yes. This was simultaneously posted in both groups. Thanks.